# how can I draw a boxplot with fix wieght and correct label?

Tags: r, boxplot

I write this code but I can't fix width of box part and recently labels shows vertically! but yesterday it had work correct!!!

```
dt=rnorm(100)
l=c("min:","1st Qu:","median:","3rd Qu:","max:")
bxp <- boxplot(dt, axes=TRUE,col = '#fb9a99')
v=round(bxp$stats,2)
mtext(paste(l,v),side = 4, at=bxp$stats[c(1,2,3,4,5)], line=-5.5)
```

Comment: Use las=2 in mtext() to plot the text horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of reproducibility use set.seed() function.

```
# set seed
set.seed(1980)

# your data and text
dt <- rnorm(100)
l <- c("min:", "1st Qu:", "median:", "3rd Qu:", "max:")

# your boxplot
# with boxwex parameter you control the width of the boxes
bxp <- boxplot(dt, 
               axes = TRUE, 
               col = '#fb9a99', 
               boxwex = 0.5)

v <- round(bxp$stats, 2)

# your text
# with las parameter you control orientation of the text
mtext(paste(l, v), 
      side = 4, 
      at = bxp$stats[c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)], 
      line = -10.5, 
      las = 1)
```

Comment: First thanks, second Do you know how I can reduce space between boxplot and frame (axes=TRUE) around that? (inside space not outside)

Comment: Take a look at par()  function... Especially parameters that control plot margins....